# Logout button in bootstrap dropdown menu not working after rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, routes

Evening all,

I have a logout button that was working absolutely fine in a twitter drop down menu. However now after compiling the assets and then cleaning them, the logout button redirects to localhost:3000/logout instead of calling the destroy action in the controller and redirecting to the root path and resetting the session.

my code is as follows, any help would be great, note this link works outside of the drop-down menu

sessions_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    reset_session
    flash[:notice] = "successfully logged out"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

routes

```
 match "/logout", to: "sessions#destroy", via: :delete
```

header

```
<li><%= link_to "Logout", "/logout", method: "delete" %></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard coding the path with `logout_path` sorted this.